# Rails custom validation based on a regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following regex that I use in my routes.rb for /type-in-something-here

```
# A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ in the middle but never starting or ending in a _
# At least 5, no more than 500 characters
```

In the routes this works well as:

```
match ':uuid' => 'room#show', :constraints => { :uuid => /[A-Za-z\d]([-\w]{,498}[A-Za-z\d])?/ }
```

I want to have this also as a validation so invalid records aren't created. So I added the following to room.rb:

```
validates_format_of :uuid, :with => /[A-Za-z\d]([-\w]{,498}[A-Za-z\d])?/i, :message => "Invalid! Alphanumerics only."
```

But this validates_format_of isn't working, and instead of adding an error it's allow the record to save.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For validation purposes, remember to add the beginning and end of string markers `\A` and `\Z`:

```
validates_format_of :uuid, :with => /\A[A-Za-z\d]([-\w]{,498}[A-Za-z\d])?\Z/i
```

Otherwise your regex will happily match any string that contains at least a letter or a digit. For some reason Rails implicitly adds the boundaries in the routes. (Probably because it embeds the regex inside a larger one to match the entire URL, with explicit checks for `/` and the end of the URL.)

Comment: Note that using `\Z` at the end of the regex allows a trailing newline. You probably want `\z` instead. (Apologies for commenting on an old issue.)

Answer (score 11):

using something like this

```
validates :uuid, :format => {:with => /[A-Za-z\d]([-\w]{,498}[A-Za-z\d])?/i},
                 :message => "your message"
```

For more check [this](http://lindsaar.net/2010/1/31/validates_rails_3_awesome_is_true)

Comment: This works well for me, however the closing brace is in the incorrect place in this example. It should be: `validates :uuid, :format => {:with => /.../i, :message => "..."}`

Answer (score 5):

```
validates :name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/,
message: "Only letters are allowed" }
```