# How to do a simple regex validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

How can perform a reguler expression to validate for either - or _ in the person username. i dont want to accept any other character like .@()$etc just - or _ so the person can either have a name like mike, mikel_mark or mike-mark. very simple. Thank you

example:

```
validate_format_of :username, with: "...."
```

Comment: Please see [Rails custom validation based on a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680771/rails-custom-validation-based-on-a-regex)

Comment: nice. i hate regex. i hope this helps me learn more

Answer (score 1):

The Rails 3 way to do validations is the following:

```
validates :username, :format => {:with => /\A[0-9a-z_]+\Z/i}
```

The form of `validate_format_of` is more Rails < 3 like and followed the "type of validation" concept, whereas the `validates` form is attribute based (you write all validations that apply to the attribute in one statement).

Check out the docs here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates